# Remove the white color around the image in Imageview

Tags: android

I have a image https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFJpO.jpg when I add in my project it appears like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcD2g.png but I want to remove the white color of the image and want to show the background.I need only the elephant in the image to be show and remove the white borders and make the layout background to be shown  is there any way I can do it.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/Head"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="70" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/jungle">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/elephant" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have to make a transparent elephant then! This not an Android problem!

Comment: U r saying I have to make transparent or I have to crap only the elephant from the img using some tool by leaving the white border.

Comment: Yes I agree with @Pavlos opinion you have to create image with transparent background  rather solid background.

Comment: add android:background:"@null"

Comment: Simply edit your elephant image in any image editor and set transparent background instead white solid background.

Comment: @Pragna,is there any reason to add this android:background:"@null" properties ?

Comment: Your image needs to have a transparent background rather than solid white.

Answer (score 1):

Use Photoshop instead.

1. Open it on Photoshop.
2. Remove / Delete the White Layer.
3. Last, Save it as PNG Format.

:)

Answer (score 0):

> This you can not do by android. You have to use some different tools
>   like Photoshop or Coral etc to create transparent image (may be .png)
>   file.